# What event exist to datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

What event exist to datagrid, that works when you change any data on datagrid?

in wpf

Comment: are you aware of MSDN?? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid%28v=vs.95%29.aspx"

Comment: he/she is now, because almost every answer includes a reference to MSDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `RowEditEnding` event:

Reference: [RowEditEnding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.roweditending%28v=vs.110%29)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example

```
<DataGrid .... SelectionChanged="selection_changed" RowEditEnding="row_Editing"  CellEditEnding="cel_Editing"       >
```

their is a nice example on this link http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=563